# how can i set relations in this problem that comment can have many repliy

Tags: nestjs, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

> Error validating model "Comment": Ambiguous self relation detected.
> The fields `comment` and `Comment` in model `Comment` both refer to
> `Comment`. If they are part of the same relation add the same relation
> name for them with `@relation(<name>)`.

```
model Comment {
 id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
 text          String          @db.VarChar
 rating        Int             @default(0)
 createdAt     DateTime        @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
 creatorId     Int
 postId        Int?
 repliedToId   Int?
 user          User            @relation(fields: [creatorId], references: [id])
 post          Post?           @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
 comment       Comment?        @relation(fields: [repliedToId], references: [id])
 Comment       Comment[]       @relation("CommentToComment")
 CommentRating CommentRating[]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `name` of the relation against `comment` attribute like this

```
...

comment     Comment?  @relation("CommentToComment", fields: [repliedToId], references: [id])
Comment     Comment[] @relation("CommentToComment")
```